# Visualising a banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set up a page where there should be a banner popping up when someone clicks on the "Get Banner Spec" box. I have gotten this far, but I cannot figure out how to call another URL in order to get the banner appearing. Could someone please let me know how this is done?

The site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-  type">
    <title>testMaria</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet"

      type="text/css">
    <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Maria Site</h1>
    <h2>Do you wanna se a banner?</h2>
    <button id="banner">Get Banner Specs</button>

    <div id="specs"> </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#banner").click(function(){
    $("#specs").append("Banner <b>Specs</b>!");    
});

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "call another URL"?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by call another Url? An image, a file with data for the specs? Another web pages content? Go to another page?

Comment: banner is probably placed in an iframe where its src = URL

Comment: With another URL, I mean call another site that then will display a banner.